# Navigate to AFC iPod Path in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ipod

So, apparently I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. It seems that I need to back up my iPod's DCIM folder in it's AFC path. The problem is that I can't figure out how to get to the AFC path in Ubuntu 16.04. In 14.04, it would take me to `afc://(device)`, while in 16.04 it just takes me to `gphoto2://[usb:002,010]/`. Apparently this isn't what I want as there is only 1 folder and it's either a blank `DCIM` folder or some folder called `store` followed by an underscore and binary code.

(Note: The iPod is running iOS 9.)

Comment: On my Xenial system I find my iPOD mounted in: `/media/andrew/ANDREW'S IP` which would vary on your system according to 1. Your username 2. Your device name. In this directory are the directories for Photos, Recordings etc. I am not sure if this is along the lines of what you are after?

Comment: @andrew.46 What I want is the old functionality 14.04 uses.

Comment: How did you locate the afc path in Trusty?

Comment: @andrew.46 You just click on the iPod/iPhone/iPad

Comment: @andrew.46 Basically you open the file manager and click on the iPhone/iPod, but it seems doing this in Xenial takes you somewhere else.

Comment: Odd, because for me the response is the same in Trusty as it is Xenial: a click on the usb icon allows access to the ipod's directory structure and the mounting is the same in `/media/$USER/$DEVICE_NAME`. I am using an ipod classic, perhaps there is different behaviour with your device. If so I will probably be no help to you :(.

Comment: @andrew.46 I'm using an iPod Touch (5th Gen)

Comment: in thunar I just needed to remove the :3 from the end of the address

Answer (score 3):

To start is due to update:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

greetings, because the first thing is to read this post

https://wiki.debian.org/es/iPhone

But to summarize use the following:

```
linux@xinial:$  lsusb -v |grep 3 |grep iSerial

  iSerial                 3 a8f72d4a6d2e3d3786fae2d328a11063b9d6947b
  iSerial                 3 FB56283B13A01C40
```

where **a8f72d4a6d2e3d3786fae2d328a11063b9d6947b** is the number of device

Now in the address bar file manager [nautilus, nemo, thunar, etc ..]

```
afc://a8f72d4a6d2e3d3786fae2d328a11063b9d6947b
```

*By the way, I speak Spanish*